# Performance of 1536 rotating CABasicAnimations

Tags: ios, core-animation, cabasicanimation

So here is the case, on my iPad screen I have 768 little clocks turning. Each clock has an hour and a minute pointer. These visual things are inside an UIImageView. I also tried to represent them via a UIBezierPath/CAShapeLayer but this didn't help performance. Of course when I try to animate all that it starts to lag. So, is there a way to optimize this? The animation code is really simple

```
CATransform3D rotationTransform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_2, 0, 0, 1);
CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:rotationTransform];
rotationAnimation.duration = 0.5f;
rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
rotationAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
[_imageViewMinutePointer.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"transform"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [`CAReplicatorLayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAReplicatorLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html). Sorry, I don’t have sample code, because I haven’t used it myself, but I’ve heard it referred to in reference to performance of many items animating at once.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps with the use of prerendered images you can offload a lot of cpu power. 1536 clocks wont be big clocks, and the number of unique pics therefore will be small.